# passing variable to sed command

Tags: sed, oracle11g, oracle-golden-gate

i need to pass a variable value to sed command. here is the description, what i am doing.

i am assigning a value to variable :

`export ALSIZE=14420
$ echo $ALSIZE
14420`

now i am using that value in sed command to read file from $ALSIZE line to end of the file. and i got the error

```
$  sed -n '$ALSIZE,$p' /db1/u04/oradata/GG11/ggserr.log
Unrecognized command: $ALSIZE,$p ====== >>
```

used the variable value in "" (double quotes) still got error.

```
$ sed -n '"$ALSIZE",$p' /db1/u04/oradata/GG11/ggserr.log
Unrecognized command: "$ALSIZE",$p  ===== >>>
```

i am getting response back

```
$ sed -n '14420,$p' /db1/u04/oradata/GG11/ggserr.log

2013-12-26 06:36:17  INFO    OGG-01026  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, dpsbprd.prm:  Rolling over remote file ./dirdat/siebel/r1003911.

2013-12-26 06:43:31  INFO    OGG-01026  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, dpsbprd.prm:  Rolling over remote file ./dirdat/siebel/r1003912.
2013-12-26 11:07:47  INFO    OGG-01026  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, dpsbprd.prm:  Rolling over remote file ./dirdat/siebel/r1003913.
```

what is the mistake i am doing. could you please advice ?

Comment: You need understand the difference of "double quotes" and "single quotes" in sed

Answer (score 1):

All of these would work:

```
sed -n $ALSIZE',$p' /db1/u04/oradata/GG11/ggserr.log
sed -n "$ALSIZE"',$p' /db1/u04/oradata/GG11/ggserr.log
sed -n "$ALSIZE,\$p" /db1/u04/oradata/GG11/ggserr.log
```

The key is understanding how quoting works:

- You can quote part of a string or all of it: `hello`, `hel'lo'`, `'hello'`, `'hel''lo'` are all the same to the shell
- Shell variables within double quotes are expanded to their value: `"$ALSIZE"` is expanded to `"14420"`, which doesn't need to be quoted, so you could write simply `$ALSIZE` without quoting
- Shell variables within single quotes are not expanded, so `'$ALSIZE'` will be used a the literal text "$ALSIZE" which is not what you want
- In the `"$ALSIZE,\$p"` example the second `$` has to be escaped to prevent the shell from expanding the `$p` variable, which probably has no value

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes means that the '$' in $ALSIZE is expanded as a literal "\$ALSIZE". What happens if you rewrite it to:

```
sed -n $ALSIZE',$p' /db1/u04/oradata/GG11/ggserr.log
```

(leaving the single quotes until after the $ALSIZE variable)?

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes:

```
kent$  s=5

kent$  seq 10 |sed -n "$s,$ p"
5
6
7
8
9
10
```